# How to change date format in laravel Query Builder from "2016-03-12" to "12-Mar-2016"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How to change date-format in laravel from "2016-03-12" to "12-Mar-2016"

```
$results = DB::table('customers as cust')
        ->where('cust.id',$id)
        ->select("cust.*","cust.cust_dob as dob")
        ->first();
```

Should I use laravel raw query.

I tried this,

```
 ->select("cust.*","DATE_FORMAT(cust.cust_dob, '%d-%M-%Y') as formatted_dob")
```

Any guide on this please.

Comment: you can use raw query builder .. It will look like normal query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) for datetime so you can write it like following code:

```
$results = DB::table('customers as cust')
            ->where('cust.id',$id)
            ->select("cust.*","cust.cust_dob as dob")
            ->first();
echo $results->dob->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 36):

Try to use this:

```
$results = DB::table('customers as cust')
             ->where('cust.id',$id)
             ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(cust.cust_dob, "%d-%b-%Y") as formatted_dob'))
             ->first();
```

Comment: runs the date_format on every row, if number increases, performance will go down

Answer (score 9):

As there is no way except using raw query, I am using like this. It worked for me.

```
->select("cust.*", DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(cust.cust_dob, '%d-%b-%Y') as formatted_dob"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Carbon's `->format('m/d/Y');` to change format.

Or you can just use `selectRaw` to build your queries.

Also, you can try to use date mutators by settting `$dateFormat` to date format you want to use:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Laravel gives a opportunity to define accessors/mutators. Which you can use in this case rather than to do it via Queries.

i would add method in Customer model class

```
public function getCustDobAttribute($value) {
    return //Format the value Which represent the value in database;
}
```

**Example:**
Imagine you want retrieve customer name, You want get it as First charterer capital and the rest small.

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

**Reference:**

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators